# Get arguments from all calls to a throttled function (lodash)

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm reworking some logger logic that batches writes together. This sounded like the perfect job for [lodash's throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/#throttle) function, but soon found out that by replacing the setTimeouts with throttle, the code was still much uglier than I would have hoped for. This code should give the basic idea (there's a little more to the functions than what's shown).

```
let queue = []

function write(message) {
  queue.push(message)
  scheduleFlushOfQueue()
}

const scheduleFlushOfQueue = _.throttle(function flushQueue() {
  const dataToWrite = queue.join('\n')
  queue = []
  fs.promises.appendFile(path, dataToWrite)
}, 100, { leading: false })
```

As you can see, I'm having to use a global queue variable in order to pass arguments from write() to scheduleFlushOfQueue() (gross ). Ideally, I would want _.throttle to just pass in a list of parameters that came from all invocations so that I wouldn't have have to manage a global variable, but it doesn't do that.

I'm not very familiar with Lodash and what other kinds of functions it provides, so I thought I would reach out to the stack overflow community to see if anyone could think of a better way to write this kind of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a closure with the `queue` variable using a factory function (`createWriteQueue`). The function creates the `queue`, and returns the function to handle it (`scheduleFlushOfQueue`, and `write`):

```js
const createWriteQueue = () => {
  let queue = []

  const scheduleFlushOfQueue = _.throttle(function flushQueue() {
    const dataToWrite = queue.join('\n')
    queue = []
    console.log(dataToWrite) // fs.promises.appendFile(path, dataToWrite)
  }, 100, { leading: false })

  return {
    write(message) {
      queue.push(message)
      scheduleFlushOfQueue()
    },
    scheduleFlushOfQueue,
  }
}

const q1 = createWriteQueue()

q1.write('a')
q1.write('b')
q1.write('c')

const q2 = createWriteQueue()

q2.write('d')
q2.write('e')
q2.write('f')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Another option is to create a class that does the same. Use arrow functions to bind `this` automatically.

```js
class WriteQueue {
  queue = []
  
  scheduleFlushOfQueue = _.throttle(() => {
    const dataToWrite = this.queue.join('\n')
    this.queue = []
    console.log(dataToWrite) // fs.promises.appendFile(path, dataToWrite)
  }, 100, { leading: false })
  
  write = (message) => {
    this.queue.push(message)
    this.scheduleFlushOfQueue()
  }
}

const q1 = new WriteQueue()

q1.write('a')
q1.write('b')
q1.write('c')

const q2 = new WriteQueue()

q2.write('d')
q2.write('e')
q2.write('f')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```